# Adding the OR operator to a quizz form makes it accept any answers

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I'm having a weird problem when trying to create a question form that is validated with Javascript:

If I write my validation like this:

```
if (typedValue === "myAnswer" && clearedLevels === 1){doStuff}
```

Everything works. But I want to create several correct answers, so I write:

```
 if (typedValue === "myAnswer"||"secondAnswer" && clearedLevels === 1){doStuff}
```

..and all of a sudden anything written to the input form is accepted as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A correct way of writing it is :

```
if ((typedValue === "myAnswer" || typedValue === "secondAnswer") && clearedLevels === 1) { doStuff() }
```

You **cannot** combine the condition `(x === y || x === z)` as `x === y || z` and expect the same results.

Answer (score 1):

Any non-empty string in Javascript is `true` (yes, even the string `"false"`). Since `"secondAnswer` isn't empty, it's evaluated as `true`, and `OR`ed with any other condition will result in `true`.

You are missing a comparison of `typedValue` to this literal, and presumably, brackets around the `typedValue` comparisons, since `&&` has higher precedence than `||`:

```
if ((typedValue === "myAnswer" || typedValue === "secondAnswer") && 
    clearedLevels === 1) {
    // doStuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

extending Akash Pradhan answer you could write

```
if (typedValue == "myAnswer" || typedValue == "secondAnswer" && clearedLevels == 1) { doStuff() }
```

but since the [`&&` has precedence over the `||` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) it would evaluate

```
  if (typedValue == "myAnswer" || (typedValue == "secondAnswer" && clearedLevels == 1)) { doStuff() }
```